# List object has AttributeError for a method in a self-defined class

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, object-oriented-analysis

I'm trying to calculate weighted averages. We just started OOP and I'm not sure if my problem is with that or lists.

Here is my code:

```
class WeightedAverage:
    """ Class to compute weighted averages. """

    def __init__(self):
        """ Creates empty lists. """
        scoresList = []
        weightsList = []

    def addScore(self,score,weight):
        scoreBool = checkScore(score)
        weightBool = checkWeight(weight)

        if scoreBool == True and weightBool == True:
            scoresList.append(score)
            weightsList.append(weight)


    def checkScore(scr):
        if scr in range(1,10):
            scrBl = True
        else:
            scrBl = False
        return scrBl


    def checkWeight(wgt):
        if wgt in [0.5,1,1.5,2]:
            wgtBl = True
        else:
            wgtBl = False
        return wgtBl


    def getScores(self,scoresList):
        return scoresList

    def getWeights(self,weightsList):
        return weightsList

    def getWAvg(self,scoresList,weightsList):
        wAvg = [scoresList*weightsList for scoresList,weightsList in zip(scoresList,weightsList)]
        return wAvg


# For testing
def main():
    scoresData = [1.5,3,9.2]
    weightsData = [0.5,2,1]

    wAvg = scoresData.getWAvg(scoresData,weightsData)
    print(wAvg)    # should display 15.95/3
```

Where main() is defined as a means of testing the code in my class.

When I run main(), I get the following TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\WeightAverages.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:\WeightAverages.py", line 54, in main
    wAvg = scoresData.getWAvg(scoresData,weightsData)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getWAvg'
```

Is this a problem with my class or is it just a list issue? This is my first time writing OO code so I'm not entirely sure this is even right!

Comment: did you missed creation of instance of ```WeightedAverage``` ?

Comment: This runs for me under both Py2.7 and Py3.6 without error. Did you update your code?

Comment: No but I did try what @ManojJadhav suggested and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

you should do this

```
class WeightedAverage(object):
""" Class to compute weighted averages. """

    def __init__(self):
        """ Creates empty lists. """
        scoresList = []
        weightsList = []

    def addScore(self,score,weight):
        scoreBool = checkScore(score)
        weightBool = checkWeight(weight)

        if scoreBool == True and weightBool == True:
            scoresList.append(score)
            weightsList.append(weight)


    def checkScore(scr):
        if scr in range(1,10):
            scrBl = True
        else:
            scrBl = False
        return scrBl


    def checkWeight(wgt):
        if wgt in [0.5,1,1.5,2]:
            wgtBl = True
        else:
            wgtBl = False
        return wgtBl


    def getScores(self,scoresList):
        return scoresList

    def getWeights(self,weightsList):
        return weightsList

   def getWAvg(self,scoresList,weightsList):
        wAvg = [scoresList*weightsList for scoresList,weightsList in zip(scoresList,weightsList)]
        return wAvg


# For testing
def main():
    scoresData = [1.5,3,9.2]
    weightsData = [0.5,2,1]
    obj = WeightedAverage()
    wAvg = obj.getWAvg(scoresData,weightsData)
    print(wAvg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Manoj Jadhav's comment seems to be right. In order to call the getWAvg function, you need to create an instance of the WeightedAverage class.

Here's a version of your code where an instance is created, and used to call the getWavg function. Also notice I changed getWAvg.

```
class WeightedAverage:
    """ Class to compute weighted averages. """

    def __init__(self):
        """ Creates empty lists. """
        scoresList = []
        weightsList = []

    def addScore(self,score,weight):
        scoreBool = checkScore(score)
        weightBool = checkWeight(weight)

        if scoreBool == True and weightBool == True:
            scoresList.append(score)
            weightsList.append(weight)


    def checkScore(scr):
        if scr in range(1,10):
            scrBl = True
        else:
            scrBl = False
        return scrBl


    def checkWeight(wgt):
        if wgt in [0.5,1,1.5,2]:
            wgtBl = True
        else:
            wgtBl = False
        return wgtBl


    def getScores(self,scoresList):
        return scoresList

    def getWeights(self,weightsList):
        return weightsList

    def getWAvg(self,scoresList,weightsList):
        wAvg = sum([s*w for s,w in zip(scoresList,weightsList)]) / len(scoresList)
        return wAvg


# For testing
def main():
    scoresData = [1.5,3,9.2]
    weightsData = [0.5,2,1]

    instance = WeightedAverage()
    wAvg = instance.getWAvg(scoresData,weightsData)

    print(wAvg)    # should display 15.95/3
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!